# Can I skip row form select based on condition?

Tags: sql, if-statement, skip

Let's say I have:

```
ID - value
-----------
1  - pass
2  - pass
3  - pass
4  - fail
```

and my select is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

However, I wish to add a condition that only if this value will be "pass" then return.. otherwise return nothing.

So if I do `WHERE value="pass"` then it actually gives me ID 3, this is what I do not want, I prefer nothing if the last value is not "pass".

So something like:

```
IF value != "pass" THEN SKIP?
```

Thank you

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Please tag your SQL requests always with your DBMS.

Comment: What is "nothing"? Empty string or an empty result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? This should allow you to print blank if the last value is not 'pass'.

```
with cte AS
(
  select 1 as id , 'pass' as VALUE
  union
  select 2 as id , 'pass' as VALUE  
  union
  select 3 as id , 'pass' as VALUE
  union
  select 4 as id , 'fail' as VALUE
)  
select 
   id , 
   value 
from cte
where id = (select max(id) from cte) and value = 'pass';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution. You want the ID to be the maximum ID and the value to be 'pass'. Hence:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable 
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable)
AND value = 'pass';
```

Answer (score 0):

Only return `id` when the `value='pass'`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN value='pass' THEN id ELSE '' END
FROM mytable
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```